# Javascript to read local file works on windows but not on linux

Tags: javascript, linux, window

I have a small Javascript, which is supposed to read the content of a local text file and display it on the browsers screen.
It works on windows 7 with a current firefox, but it does not work on fedroa 20 with a current firefox or chrome.
Here is the code:

```
<h1>View file content</h1>

<script>
function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                alert(allText);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

function read_status()
{
    readTextFile('file:///tmp/status.txt');
}

</script>

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Current status" onclick="read_status(); " />
```

Why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: How you get file on Linux. Like that ```file:///tmp/status.txt``` ?

Comment: Just understand that you should not rely on this behavior. I'm surprised Firefox allows this out of the box (or did you change something?) Local file system access is a thing of the past with JavaScript. Use a server-side technology to read the file contents from the file system for you. You can still use AJAX to make a request to the server, it will just be via a URL (e.g. `http://localhost/myapp/pleasegetmefile.php?path=/tmp/statust.txt` -- but even this is dangerous, as you could request sensitive files).

Comment: I also wondered if this is maybe a default security setting, which differs from OS to OS. I did not consciously change any settings. The is created by a local script - I wanted it to be very simple. I could implement a small local web server, but that seems overkill for my intention.

Comment: You can use object with text data. Here is the [example](http://www.rgagnon.com/jsdetails/js-0102.html)  . If you need to serve file from another part of filesystem, so you definitely need server serving needed folder (or single file).

Comment: Can I make the object autoreloading? Idealy it would monitor the file for changes, but also periodic reloading would be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and questions - you directed me to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for what I wanted, the answer is really simple, no need for java script, just plain html:

```
<h1>Status </h1>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" > 
<object width="100%" height="100%" type="text/plain" data="/tmp/status.txt" border="0" >
```